# Matplotlib - 24h Timeline graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a timeline that shows the average number of messages sent over a 24h period. So far, I have managed to format both of the axes. The Y-axis already has the correct data in it.

[image: Graph]

These are the lists of data:

- dates[] #a list of datetimes reduced to hours and minutes
- values[] #a list of int

Now, for some time, I have tried to insert data into the graph. I have managed to insert the data now, but I assume that the X-axis is causing some problems because of formatting.

```
    lineColor = "#f0f8ff"
    chartColor = "#f0f8ff"
    backgroundColor = "#36393f"
    girdColor = "#8a8a8a"
    dates = []
    values = []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval=2)
    d_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(d_fmt)
    ax.fill(dates, values)
    ax.plot(dates, values, color=Commands.lineColor)
    ax.set_xlim(["00:00", "23:59"])
    plt.fill_between(dates, values,)

    # region ChartDesign
    ax.set_title('Amount of Messages')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=Commands.chartColor)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors=Commands.chartColor)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', colors=Commands.chartColor)
    ax.set_ylabel('Messages', color=Commands.chartColor)
    plt.grid(True, color=Commands.girdColor)
    ax.set_facecolor(Commands.backgroundColor)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_color(Commands.chartColor)
    ax.spines["left"].set_color(Commands.chartColor)
    ax.spines["top"].set_color(Commands.chartColor)
    ax.spines["right"].set_color(Commands.chartColor)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor(Commands.backgroundColor)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    # endregion
```

There are similar questions, but they aren't much use for me.

Comment: This question has too much detail and lacks information (yes, that is possible). The formatting what color your chart has, is most likely not related to your problem (although also missing from your example). However, the exact format of your data is essential because datetime objects can be provided in different formats. You should provide an example of your data that allows others to reproduce your problem. Post your code into a freshly started IDE - this is what we see and this is all we know about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have any sample data, I created a simple data and made a graph. The 0:00 time on the timeline is a challenge, so I need to be creative. I have replaced the last 0:00 with 24:00. Then I set the time interval value to 48 as the interval on the X axis. In your code, it will be every 2 hours. I have removed the code that I deemed unnecessary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lineColor = "#f0f8ff"
chartColor = "#f0f8ff"
backgroundColor = "#36393f"
girdColor = "#8a8a8a"

date_rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', '2020-12-02', freq='1H')
dates = date_rng.strftime('%H:%M').tolist()
values = np.random.randint(0,25, size=25)
dates[-1] = '24:00'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))

hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval=48)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)

# ax.fill(dates, values)
ax.plot(dates, values, color=lineColor)
ax.fill_between(dates, values,)

# region ChartDesign
ax.set_title('Amount of Messages', color=chartColor)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=chartColor)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors=chartColor)
# ax.tick_params(which='major', colors=chartColor)
ax.set_ylabel('Messages', color=chartColor)
ax.grid(True, color=girdColor)
ax.set_facecolor(backgroundColor)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_color(chartColor)
ax.spines["left"].set_color(chartColor)
ax.spines["top"].set_color(chartColor)
ax.spines["right"].set_color(chartColor)
fig.set_facecolor(backgroundColor)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]